# Tangled up file paths trying to take Desktop off of OneDrive

Tags: windows-10, path, desktop, onedrive, files-folders

So, I don’t like that my desktop folder is in OneDrive. It messed with the performance of my old PC, and I was able to change where the desktop folder lived on my old one without issue.

I now have a new PC, and I went to do the same thing. Rather, I tried to. I seem to have tangled up some directories and folders and I'm worried about trying solutions for similar issues because I might mess it up even worse if I can't adapt those solutions correctly.

So, here's where I started. I went to move it initially, I went to properties and clicked the location tab, and then clicked the Move button. I went to put it onto `C:\` (although I've since tried it on other places with the same result of it not working) and I get

`Can't redirect child into a parent. the specified path is invalid.`

Okay, I understand that (I thought). I instead moved it to a different drive entirely, with the intention of moving it back to the c drive right afterward. When I tried this, it said

`failed to build the list of regular subdirectories under d system volume information.`

A workaround I found was to say no when it asks this:

`Do you want to move all of the files from the old location to the new location?`

That seemed to work, as my desktop is now desktop-y (has the recycle bin etc) but now my Users folder only has "Public" in it, no other folder with any names, like the folder with my name-- lcapo-- should be there, but it's not.

What’s weird is that it just seems to be mega invisible? I was able to download an `.exe` to that folder and even access it but ONLY by copy pasting the actual path. I did change it so I can at least see invisible folders now. However, there's still no folder with lcapo. It says "Default."

Going to properties in the Home bar at the top, when I have Desktop selected, gives me this:

[image: screenshot]

Also, the folder that is being used as my desktop is called Users and it even has that little desktop icon as its picture/thumbnail. The Public folder is visible on my desktop as well as in the file explorer.

There's a hidden Desktop folder here too but I can't do anything with it. On the left you may see a normal folder called Desktop but that was one I made when trying a solution online; it's nothing more than a normal folder with nothing in it.

Any other attempts I've made at moving it results in

`The folder can't be moved here: Can't move the folder because there is a folder in the same location that can't be redirected. Access is denied.`

I doubt my explanation was thorough or even coherent here, but I hope it's enough info to help me untangle this mess; here's a screenshot with some other information that I hope can help as well.

[image: In the Default users folder]

The items in this Desktop folder are not the ones that are in the folder that is currently my desktop, the one labeled Users.

If there's other screenshots/more info you could use, just let me know where I have to go and I'm happy to do it.

Comment: I would at this point just give up, backup my data and do either a repair installation or a clean Win installation. The default location of Win desktop is `C:\Users\<username>\Desktop`, but if your user doesn't even have a home folder in `C:\Users` something's really broken. I can't figure out how your desktop even _could_ end up in OneDrive, unless someone moved it there on purpose. Even my Win11 foray didn't have that, and I used MS account as login.

Comment: Why do you have screenshots for the default user profile?  Anyways, did you disable OneDrive from synchronizing your Desktop, before you tried to move it to another location?

Comment: @Peregrino69 I don't know, dude. I literally booted up my new PC and it was like that. I didn't do anything differently that I can think of during setup.

Comment: @Ramhound That's the only profile I have. There's Default and there's Public. I honestly can't remember if I did disable OneDrive first. That may be how I messed it up.

Comment: Your user profile should be named after your username, the default user profile, is a template and public is a different user profile.

Comment: @Ramhound yes, I know. that's my problem. I only have those two listed, even when I unhide the folders, however my lcapo folder (the one that is my username profile) is entirely invisible or I can't find where it ended up when I tried to move my desktop off of onedrive (which was the default location for some reason). I can still access it, but only if I copy-paste the actual path.

Answer (score 0):

The fact that the `Public` folder is displaying on your Desktop and `Users` is displaying under `This PC` and the `shell:UsersFilesFolder` makes me think you redirected the folder to `C:\Users`.

Open `regedit.exe` and navigate to:

- `HKCU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\User Shell Folders`

and check the path of `Desktop` in the right-hand pane. Since you never properly turned off backup, change the value to:
= `%USERPROFILE%\OneDrive\Desktop`

Then sign out and back in. If `Desktop` is now showing under `This PC`, re-enable OneDrive and turn off backup for the Desktop. Then you should be able ot specify any locaiton via the `Location` tab in the `Properties` dialog. Then move files and folders you want on your Desktop to the folder you specified in the re-location.

### When you re-direct folcers via the `Location`tab, ***Do not specify the parent and expect the folder to be created with the default name***, rather create the folder beforehand (if necessary) and be sure to specify it as the location.